# Regular curve which normal lines pass through a fixed point

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, parametrization

I have the following question:

> Assume that $α$ is a regular curve in $R^2$ and all the normal lines of
>   the curve pass though the origin. Prove that $α$ is contained in a
>   circle around the origin. (Recall the normal line at $α(t)$ is the line
>   through $α(t)$ pointing in the direction of the normal vector $N(t)$.)

My attempt:

I know that if $α(t)$ is contained in a circle, then the curvature is constant. So I have to prove that the curvature at $α(t)$ is constant. I also know that the equations of the normal lines through the origin that passes through arbitrary points on the curve $α(t)$ denoted as $(t, α(t))$ have the equations:

$$α(t) = \frac{t}{α'(t)}$$

I'm confused on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\alpha'(t) \perp N(t) \parallel \alpha(t)$ for all $t$, so $\alpha' \cdot \alpha = 0$,

therefore

$$\frac{d\|\alpha\|}{dt} = \frac{\alpha\cdot\alpha'}{\|\alpha\|} = 0,$$

so $\|\alpha\|$ is constant. $~~~~\square$

Comment: How does this prove the curvature is constant?

Comment: I skipped that part. I just showed directly that $\alpha$ is contained in a circle with radius $|\alpha|$ around the origin.

Answer (score 5):

More than a year has passed. I hope my solution still helps.

I suppose you know the Frenet frame and the Frenet-Serret formulas. Let me denote the unit tangent vector and unit normal vector at $\alpha(t)$ by $\mathbf{T}(t)$ and $\mathbf{N}(t)$. Finally, denote $\mathbf{B}(t)=\mathbf{T}(t)\times\mathbf{N}(t)$.

My strategy is to prove that

1. $||\alpha||$ is constant, so that (the trace of) $\alpha$ is contained in some sphere centered around $\mathbf{0}=(0,0,0)$.
2. $\mathbf{B}(t)$ is constant, so that the curve is a plane curve, i.e., it lies on some plane.

For 1, we differentiate $||\alpha||
^2$ with respect to $t$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d||\alpha(t)||^2}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(t)\cdot\alpha(t)=2\alpha(t)\cdot\alpha'(t)
\end{align*}
Since the normal line at $\alpha(t)$ passes through $\alpha(t)$ and $\mathbf{0}$, thus the vector $\alpha(t)-\mathbf{0}=\alpha(t)$ is parallel to the normal vector $\mathbf{N}(t)$, and so it is orthogonal to the tangent vector $\mathbf{T}(t)=\alpha'(t)$. Therefore $\alpha(t)\cdot\alpha'(t)=0$. Hence, $||\alpha||^2$ is constant, and so is $||\alpha||$.

For 2, we differentiate $\mathbf{B}(t)$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathbf{B}(t)}{dt}&=\mathbf{T}'(t)\times\mathbf{N}(t)+\mathbf{T}(t)\times\mathbf{N}'(t) \\
&=\alpha''(t)\times\frac{\alpha''(t)}{|\alpha''(t)|}+\alpha'(t)\times(\lambda\alpha'(t)) \\
&=0+\lambda(\alpha'(t)\times\alpha'(t)) \\
&=0
\end{align*}
Here I write $\mathbf{N}(t)=\lambda\alpha(t)$ because $\alpha(t)$ is parallel to $\mathbf{N}(t)$ as aforementioned. This proves 2.

Since the intersection of a sphere and a plane is precisely a circle, we conclude that (the trace of) $\alpha$ is contained in a circle. Moreover, since the normal lines are contained in the plane, thus the centre of the circle is the origin.  $\qquad\square$

Comment: The factorization with $\lambda$ seems off? Also, can you elaborate why "since the normal lines are contained in the plane, thus the centre of the circle is the origin". Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @IntegrateThis Sorry I'm not sure about the 1st question. I am essentially just using the basic fact that the cross-product is bilinear over $\mathbb{R}$. For the 2nd question, having a second thought about it I think my claim here is wrong. The correct reasoning should be "since the normal vector $\mathbf{N}(t)$ is parallel to the vector $\alpha(t)$, thus the centre is the origin". Thanks for the question.

Comment: Right, I was mistaken with the factorization of $\lambda$ comment.

Answer (score 2):

If all normal lines pass through a fixed point, then for all $s \in I$, there is a $\lambda = \lambda(s)$ such that

$$\alpha(s) + \lambda(s)n(s) = p,$$ where $p$ is our supposed fixed point. So, deriving we are left with:

$$\alpha'(s) + \lambda'(s)n(s) + \lambda(s)(-k(s)t(s) - \tau(s)b(s)) = 0$$
$$t + \lambda'n - \lambda k t - \lambda \tau b = 0 \implies (1-\lambda k)t + \ldots$$

But $\{t,n,b\}$ form an orthogonal basis, and so it is true that $(1 - \lambda k) = 0, \lambda' = 0$ and $\lambda \tau = 0$.

So $\lambda' = 0 \implies \lambda = \text{constant}$.
Also, $k = \frac{1}{\lambda}$, $\tau = 0$.

See the curvature is constant and equal to $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, which is the curvature for a circle when $\lambda = R$, $R$ being the circle's radius. And so we can contain $\alpha(s)$ in a circle centered on the origin - it need only have radius $R > \lambda$.

Comment: the curve is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so we need to prove that $\lambda$ is positive too, right?

Comment: Actually, planar curves having constant curvature are well-characterized: they are either a straight line or a circle (or their segments). Then since the curvature can't be zero in this case, we must be in the case of a circle. We can assume $\lambda$ will be positive as this is linked only to a choice of orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Assume WLOG that $\alpha$ is parametrized by arc-length. The normal line at the point $\alpha(s)$ is given by:

$$\alpha(s)+\lambda n(s),$$

where $n$ is the unit normal.

By your hypothesis, for each $s$ there exists a $\lambda(s)$ such that

$$\alpha(s)+\lambda(s)n(s)=0.$$

Hence

$$\|\alpha(s)\|=|\lambda(s)|,$$

so it suffices to see that $\lambda$ is constant.

Comment: how does this prove that the curvature is constant? Is lambda the curvature?

Comment: @VarunIyer It's not a full proof, I gave you a hint. $\lambda$ is the parameter of the normal line at a point. $\lambda(s)$ is the value of this parameter at which the line meets the origin.

Comment: I understand that, how do you prove that $||\alpha(s)||=|\lambda(s)|$? I don't understand how you reached this statement from the statment above it.

Comment: $\|\alpha(s)\|=\|-\lambda(s)n(s)\|$ and $n$ is unitary.

Comment: Ok how does that prove that $\lambda(s)$ is constant? And I'm confused how to relate this to the curvature.

Comment: It doesn't. There are other ways of seeing that $\alpha$ is contained in a circle, besides checking the curvature is constant. Try differentiating the different symbols involved. For instance: 
$\frac{d}{ds}\|\alpha\|^2=2\langle \alpha,\alpha'\rangle$.

Comment: so as an alternative, could i assume that a(t) parameterizes to a circle and prove the curvature is constant?

Comment: A curve $\alpha$ is contained in a circle if and only if its norm $\|\alpha\|$ is constant (try drawing a picture).

Comment: I'm still not able to see that. Do you have a link where i could understand this more? I'm not that proficient with differential geo.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=\beta \mathbb{n}$ where $\beta$ is a function of $s$. Now by definition 
$$\mathbb{t}=\frac{d\alpha}{ds}=\frac{d\beta}{ds}\mathbb{n}-\beta\kappa\mathbb{t}$$

This implies that $\frac{d\beta}{ds}=0$ and that $\kappa=-\frac{1}{\beta}$

Comment: What is $n$ here? And what equation are you using

Comment: The derivative of the normal is curvature times tangent.

Comment: could you explain your solution a bit more in depth? I apologize but I'm not that proficient in differential geometry and i'm trying to understand, both algebraically and conceptually, your solution. Thanks.